# Average number of rows by hour based on total number of days

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

Dear all

In PowerBI, using DirectQuery, I would like to have the sum of of occurences by hour per day, divided by the total number of days

Let me provide you with a sample data.

***DataTable:***

```
ID;DATE;HOUR
715;2019-10-19;15:47:37
181;2019-10-19;15:56:11
349;2019-10-19;15:57:25
6ec;2019-10-19;15:58:16
57e;2019-10-19;16:02:35
860;2019-10-19;16:03:42
7a5;2019-10-19;16:03:52
978;2019-10-19;16:05:19
da0;2019-10-20;11:00:45
c2d;2019-10-20;23:04:53
355;2019-10-20;23:04:53
4f5;2019-10-20;23:05:10
396;2019-10-21;14:42:24
5f7;2019-10-21;14:43:37
93a;2019-10-21;14:55:36
a44;2019-10-21;14:59:21
264;2019-10-21;15:05:20
f48;2019-10-21;15:07:01
```

And a summarized Dimension Table with the values present in *DataTable:*

***DimHourTable:***

```
COMPLETEHOUR;HOUR24
15:47:37;15
15:56:11;15
15:57:25;15
15:58:16;15
16:02:35;16
16:03:42;16
16:03:52;16
16:05:19;16
11:00:45;11
23:04:53;23
23:04:53;23
23:05:10;23
14:42:24;14
14:43:37;14
14:55:36;14
14:59:21;14
15:05:20;15
15:07:01;15
```

*Note: Relationship with Both Directions filter between DataTable[HOUR] and DimHourTable[COMPLETEHOUR]*

I'm now doing this:

```
formula1
Occurrences = COUNTA( DataTable[id] )

formula2 
CountDays = DISTINCTCOUNT( DataTable[date] )

formula3
Avg_Occurrences = DIVIDE( [Occurences] , [CountDays] )
```

Then I'm putting in a matrix the following

Rows: DimHourTable[HOUR24]

Values: Avg_Occurrences

With that Sample Data, this is the average I'm getting.

```
11 -> 1
14 -> 4
15 -> 3
16 -> 4
23 -> 3
```

It ends up dividing by the number of days that contains that specific hour.

But, in reality, I would like to have this:

```
11 -> 0.33
14 -> 1.33
15 -> 2
16 -> 1.33
23 -> 1
```

I would like to divide the occurrences by the total number of days present in the *DataTable*, independent if it contains that specific hours or not.

Does someone have an idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this for formula2

`CountDays = CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( DataTable[date] ), ALL ( 'DataTable' ) )`

When you are using slicers, you can also try

`CountDays = CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( DataTable[date] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'DataTable' ) )`

The ALL and ALLSELECTED functions will remove the filtercontext that is created by `DimHourTable[HOUR24]`, that you put on rows in your matrix-visual

Comment: Great! That matches perfectly what I was looking for!
Thank you very much!